# PHP Regex Remove Periods That Appear Next to Each Other

Tags: php, regex, period

I am working with a body of text that sometimes includes periods that occur right next to each other. Example:
*Today is a nice day....."It is almost time for lunch"..*
How can I turn that into this:
*Today is a nice day. "It is almost time for lunch".*

I have tried using `$_input = preg_replace("/.+/",".",$_input);` but this seems to remove everything except a bunch of periods, which it leaves there.

Any help at all is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` character is a [meta character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in regular expressions meaning "match any character except newline (by default)". So if you want to match a literal period you need to escape it in your regex:

```
$_input = preg_replace("/\.+/",".",$_input);
```

Comment: Beat me to it, to see a list of all reserved characters: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: Thanks so much guys! That fixed most of the problem, however I am still having this occur a lot ".. (one quote followed by 2 periods) and the `$_input = preg_replace("/\.+/",".",$_input);` doesn't seem to get rid of it. Any ideas?